# Collapse Other Nodes of TreeView on Selection of One Node

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008, treeview

I have a **treeview** control on **winform applica**tion. Here, what I want to do is:
*Collapse all other nodes at his level and expend only selected node*.
For example, suppose the scenario:
- All Subject
  + Computer Science
  + Mathematics

**Root Node** is "**All Subjects**" and two **child nodes** are **1)** Computer Science and **2)** Mathematics.
These *two child nodes have further child nodes*.

**When I select Computer Science, teh Mathematic node should be collapsed and Computer Science Node should be expanded.**
How can this be achieved ?
Suggestion to accomplish this are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** (thanks *Hans Passant*) Handel `AfterSelect` or `BeforeSelect` events, and collapse other sibling nodes. like this:

```
private void TreeViewAfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in e.Node.Parent.Nodes)
    {
        if(node != e.Node)
            node.Collapse();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not to revive an old thread, but this only collapses sibling nodes. If you want to collapse both sibling and each sibling's child nodes, I've added my own answer below, which uses recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Check the methods `Collapse()`, `CollapseAll()`, `Expand()`,  and `ExpandAll()` of treeview node.

```
treeView1.SelectedNode.Collapse();
```

Read [Collapse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.collapse%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), [CollapseAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.collapseall.aspx) and [Expand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.expand.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Ria's solution, we can collapse both sibling and each sibling's child nodes using recursion. The following works for WPF:

```
    private void CollapseAll(ItemsControl Items, bool Collapse)
    {
        foreach (object obj in Items.Items)
        {
            ItemsControl ChildControl = Items.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(obj) as ItemsControl;
            if (ChildControl != null)
            {
                CollapseAll(ChildControl, Collapse);
            }
            TreeViewItem Item = ChildControl as TreeViewItem;
            if (Item != null) Item.IsExpanded = false;
        }
    }

    private void treeView1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        TreeViewItem CurrentItem = (TreeViewItem)treeView1.SelectedItem;
        if (CurrentItem == null) return;
        if (!(CurrentItem.Parent is TreeViewItem)) return;
        TreeViewItem Parent = (TreeViewItem)CurrentItem.Parent;
        if (Parent == null) return;
        foreach (TreeViewItem TreeViewItem in Parent.Items)
        {
            if (TreeViewItem != CurrentItem)
            {
                CollapseAll(TreeViewItem, true);
                TreeViewItem.IsExpanded = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```